# make each element of an array into an array

Tags: python, arrays, list

Here is a problem I'm having in python 3 about arrays

I'm trying to make each element of an array into a single array of its own

I've tried using list() but I can't manage to get this to work

`lst = [1, 2 ,3]`

how to get the list to look like this

`lst = [[1], [2], [3]]`

seems like there is a very simple solution but i can't find one, (tried looking it up but i can't word my issue properly that's probably why i can't find one)

Comment: Hint: Iterate over the elements and apply `list()` or list literal i.e. `[]` over them. Also, read about list comprehension (and `map()`).

Answer (score 1):

My take on the problem:

```
lst = [1, 2 ,3]

new_lst = [[i] for i in lst]
print(new_lst)
```

Output:

```
[[1], [2], [3]]
```